# krb5.conf syntax error, issue with setting up the basic file

Tags: kerberos

I'm trying to get the kb5 file to run so that I can setup AD login for my box. when I run a kinit command I get an error stating that 
"Improper format of Kerberos configuraiton file while initilizing Kerberos 5 library"

I'm relatively new to setting up AD on a Linux box, thus I'm unsure about the proper syntax for this configuration file

anything with a ***** is the local domain that I've just commented out. so it's BOXNAME.SOMETHING.LOCAL

BOXNAME is just the name of the box in the configuration file.

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true
default_relam = BOXNAME.*****

[realms]
nwcvco01.***** {
kdc = [IPADDRESS]
default_domain = BOXNAME.*****
}

[domain_realm]
.***** = BOXNAME.*****
***** = BOXNAME.*****
```

Answer (score 0):

```
default_realm
```

is spelled incorrectly as

```
default_relam
```

Kerberos is not very tolerant of errors in krb5.conf.